# Remove all but 1 object in list based on grouping

Tags: c#, .net, linq, list

I have a list of objects with multiple properties in it. Here is the object.

```
public class DataPoint
{
    private readonly string uniqueId;
    public DataPoint(string uid)
    {
        this.uniqueId = uid;
    }

    public string UniqueId
    {
        get
        {
            return this.uniqueId;
        }
    }

    public string ScannerID { get; set; }

    public DateTime ScanDate { get; set; }
}
```

Now in my code, I have a giant list of these, hundreds maybe a few thousand.

Each data point object belongs to some type of scanner, and has a scan date. I want to remove any data points that were scanned on the same day except for the last one for a given machine.

I tried using LINQ as follows but this did not work. I still have many duplicate data points.

```
this.allData = this.allData.GroupBy(g => g.ScannerID)
                   .Select(s => s.OrderByDescending(o => o.ScanDate))
                   .First()
                   .ToList();`
```

I need to group the data points by scanner ID, because there could be data points scanned on the same day but on a different machine. I only need the last data point for a day if there are multiple.

Edit for clarification - By last data point I mean the last scanned data point for a given scan date for a given machine. I hope that helps. So when grouping by scanner ID, I then tried to order by scan date and then only keep the last scan date for days with multiple scans.

Here is some test data for 2 machines:

```
Unique ID   Scanner ID      Scan Date
A1JN221169H07  49374    2003-02-21 15:12:53.000
A1JN22116BK08  49374    2003-02-21 15:14:08.000
A1JN22116DN09  49374    2003-02-21 15:15:23.000
A1JN22116FP0A  49374    2003-02-21 15:16:37.000 
A1JOA050U900J  80354    2004-10-05 10:53:24.000 
A1JOA050UB30K  80354    2004-10-05 10:54:39.000 
A1JOA050UD60L  80354    2004-10-05 10:55:54.000 
A1JOA050UF80M  80354    2004-10-05 10:57:08.000 
A1JOA0600O202  80354    2004-10-06 08:38:26.000
```

Comment: You know you could make that a read only auto property and get rid of the backing field `public string UniqueId { get; private set; }`.

Comment: You should also shoe the desired results for that test data.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I want to remove any data points that were scanned on the same day except for the last one **for a given machine**.

So I assume you want to group by both `ScanDate` and `ScannerID`. Here is the code:

```
var result = dataPoints.GroupBy(i => new { i.ScanDate.Date, i.ScannerID })
                       .OrderByDescending(i => i.Key.Date)
                       .Select(i => i.First())
                       .ToList();
```

Comment: will it order `ScanDate` so you can use `Last`?

Comment: This will group by based on `ScanDate` and `ScannerID`, if by the last one he means the last entered value, then this is enough but if he means the last one by date, then I have to edit my answer.

Comment: I think you actually want to group on `i.ScanDate.Date` since the OP said _scanned on the same day_.  Then order by `ScanDate`.

Comment: If `OrderByDescending` then `First`, not `Last` ;)

Comment: Sorry, I meant the last data point by date. I will edit my question. Thank you

Comment: This still needs to group by `ScanDate.Date` in order to be by day.  And its the individual groups that need to be ordered `.Select(i => i.OrderBy(x => x.ScanDate).Last())`.

Comment: This answer gets me close, but when I look at the `result` variable, I am missing the other scanners. My data coming in contains 3 different machines, but I only end up with 1. The data points however do not have any multiples on the same scan date :)

Comment: @juharr As far as I understand he is looking for extra data points to remove them, so identifying them should be enough.

Comment: @RXC can you provide a sample input/output, so we can better help you.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly this is what you want.

```
var result = dataPoints.GroupBy(i => new { i.ScanDate.Date, i.ScannerID })
                       .Select(i => i.OrderBy(x => x.ScanDate).Last())
                       .ToList();
```

This groups by the scanner id and the day (`SacnnerDate.Date` will zero out the time portion), then for each grouping it orders by the `ScanDate` (since the groups are the same day this will order on the time) and takes the last.  So for each day you will get one result for each scanner which has the  latest `ScanDate` for that particular day.

Answer (score -1):

Just as an aside, the class could be defined as

```
public class DataPoint
{
  public DataPoint(string uid)
  {
    UniqueId = uid;
  }

public string UniqueId {get; private set; }
public string ScannerID { get; set; }
public DateTime ScanDate { get; set; }
```

}

Comment: This really should be a comment instead of an answer.  Kind of like the comment I already made.

Comment: @juharr, sorry I was typing when you added the comment.  However, I wanted to show how less lines of code where needed, which is to big for a comment.  That is why I prefixed with `Just as an aside`.